# ndb unable to download chrome and run (Error: read ECONNRESET)

Tags: node.js, sockets, npm, ubuntu-22.04, ndb

I have tried multiple times to now run ndb. It goes to downloading chrome then throws this error. ndb is getting installed but when opening a file with it I face this error.
`
{ndb server.js
events.js:291
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: read ECONNRESET at Pipe.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20) Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at: at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8) at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3) at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) { errno: 'ECONNRESET', code: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read'}`

I have also used commands like `"ndb download"` resulting in the same error. Any possible solution is appereciated. I have installed ndb globally. It also shows up in the npm list. however it fails to either download chrome or connecting with socket.I can't figure out the exact problem. The same error is thrown I run `ndb server.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a connection reset while trying to read data from a socket.
Try to clean an npm cache and reinstall ndb.

```
npm cache clean --force
npm uninstall -g ndb
npm install -g ndb
```